# How to flip vertically CSS corner effect?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create rounded corner to `ul` tag using CSS, I know there is `border-radius` property to do it but because of another design requirement, I can't use it.

I did a sample using `::after` and `::before`. Top corner is working well but in case of bottom, I can't make it work. What I need is just to flip vertically `lime` corner object and position it at bottom left of `ul`.

Here is the image of what I already did:

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <!--
      Need a visual blank slate?
      Remove all code in `styles.css`!
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>Menu Item 01</li>
        <li>Menu Item 02</li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 aqua;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: -40px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 lime;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

And this is the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yhdfap?file=styles.css

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I added the code and working sample.

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>` and all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I could achieve what I was trying to do, here is the CSS:

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 0 0 #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

The trick is to configure specific border-radius for top left and bottom left.

Here is full source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yhdfap?file=index.html,styles.css

And this is final result:

[image]

Corner without `border-radius`.

But why I can't use this `border-radius`? Because the goal was to get this menu:

[image]

- Top right corner (outside) is done through a `:after` element that goes from right to left and covers the corner of menu (white). This is the reason I had do "artificially" add rounded corners to menu internals.